# Difference between connecting shell commands

Tags: bash, sudo, autocomplete

My tab completion (`BASH` in [`debian`](https://www.debian.org)) shows me different numbers for combining two commands subsequently. It's somehow common sense that I can execute more commands the more privileges I have, e. g. with `sudo`.

Obviously, the ways for concatenating with `;` and `&&` are slightly different.

- What's the difference between them?
- Why does the difference in numbers decrease for accessible commands for users with `root` privileges? I would expect an increasing number (difference). (most probable/most common reason)

```bsh
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$  
Display all 2216 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date ; 
Display all 2214 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date && 
Display all 2216 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date ; sudo 
Display all 2729 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date && sudo 
Display all 2730 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date ; man 
Display all 8127 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date && man 
Display all 8127 possibilities? (y or n)
```

**EDIT 1**: I also noticed that the "number of possibilities" increases by one or two when I do this enquiry and start it all over again (except for the amount of manuals, which is somehow forseeable)…

So I did it some times for encountering a reproducible behaviour:

```bsh
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$
Display all 2221 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date ;
Display all 2221 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date &&
Display all 2221 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date ; sudo
Display all 2735 possibilities? (y or n)
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ date && sudo
Display all 2735 possibilities? (y or n)
```

**EDIT 2**: I even can't run some commands with `sudo` "enabled":

```bsh
nepumuk@nepumuk:~$ sudo alias
sudo: alias: command not found
```

So the number (more exact: the set) of commands does differ whether `sudo` is used.

Comment: If you have the "programmable completion" enabled (`shopt progcomp`), bash will try to complete not only commands, but also command line switches (and guess --most of the time wrong ;-) -- when some commands and filenames cannot be used).

Comment: I never used `shopt progcomp`. Maybe it's a default option…?

Comment: `shopt progcomp` will tell you if it's enabled or not. It's enabled by default on eg. debian.

Comment: How to know wether it's enabled?

Comment: By using `shopt progcomp` -- it will answer with `progcomp on` or `progcomp off`. You can use `shopt -s progcomp` to enable it, and `shopt -u progcomp` to disable it.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce this, I always get the same number, no matter what. What operating system are you using? Also, remember that tab completion doesn't only list commands, it will also include file names. If you try the same thing in another directory, you will see different numbers. And the tab completion after writing `sudo` won't list more commands, you don't actually have elevated privileges until the `sudo` is executed, so the completion will still run with your normal privileges.

Comment: There seems to be two questions here: The one about tab completion, as is being discussed. And one about `;` and `&&`. Please simplify to one question (I see no connection). Then ask a 2nd question.

Comment: I tried it. I get the increases as well. I see no connection to `;` and `&&`. The large increase for `man` is because the number now refers to man pages, not commands. I have no idea why the number goes up my one and then by one, when I do `date;` tab.

Comment: alias is not a program in PATH, it is a shell built-in command. So `sudo alias` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the "possibilities" being shown are not necessarily programs that you can run. For example, when you type `man`, it is likely saying that there are that many possible things you can run `man` with (e.g. `man ls`). The number of commands that you can run should be very similar regardless of whether you're root or not. If you're not root, you may still run the same programs. The programs will just give an error when they can't acquire root privileges.

As for the difference between `&&` and `;`, it's quite simple. `&&` will only run the command on the right if the command on the left completes successfully. `;` will run the command on the right regardless of how the command on the left completes. The behavior of `&&` is due to something called [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

More specifically, `&&` will only run the command on the right if the [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the command on the left is zero. The counterpart to `&&` is `||`, which will only run the command on the right if the one on the left returns a non-zero exit code.